# C++ does reinterpret_cast always return the result?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I have two classes, A, and B. A is a parent class of B, and I have a function that takes in a pointer to a class of type A, checks if it is also of type B, and if so will call another function that takes in a pointer to a class of type B.
When the function calls the other function, I supply reinterpret_cast(a) as the parameter. If this seems ambiguous here is a code example:

```
void abc(A * a) {
  if (a->IsA("B")) { //please dont worry much about this line,
                     //my real concern is the reinterpret_cast
    def(reinterpret_cast<B *>(a));
  };
};
```

So now that you know how I am calling "def", I am wondering if reinterpret_cast actually returns a pointer of type B to be sent off as the parameter to def.
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: You will get a `B*`, but it is still a very bad thing to do. It's very likely to not be the pointer you are expecting. Instead, you should do a `static_cast`

Comment: I will change it to a static_cast, thank you.

Comment: or combine the test and the cast into a dynamic_cast

Comment: Thank you that is also a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have a pointer of type `B*`, but `reinterpret_cast` isn't really great.

If you're sure the type is a `B`, use `static_cast`, if not, use `dynamic_cast` and test the pointer (if `dynamic_cast` fails, it returns `nullptr`)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/5303336

Comment: This answer would be improved if you could elaborated on why "reinterpret_cast isn't really great".

Comment: I added a link to an answer telling why it's not great and how to use different casts correctly

Answer (score 5):

reinterpret_cast will always do what you say - it is a sledghammer. You can do

```
def(reinterpret_cast<B *>(42));
```

or

```
std::string hw = "hello";
def(reinterpret_cast<B *>(hw));
```

it will always return a pointer that might point at the correct type. It assumes you know what you are doing

Answer (score 2):

`reinterpret_cast` is the result of a broken type system.  Its behaviour assumes that there is a union such as

```
 union { 
     TypeA anA;
     TypeB aB;
 } a;
```

so

```
 reinterpret_cast< B* >( a );
```

Assumes a is pointer to member anA and can then deliver the aB address.

If the type is part of the same class hierarchy, then static_cast<> would allow you to find out at compile time if there was enough information to perform the cast.  This is generally when `B` is a base class of `A` (either singly or multiply).

If there is insufficient information for static_cast to work, then it may be possible to get a dynamic_cast<> to work.  This is the case where the `B` type is derived in some way from `A`.

It is important to note that the `dynamic_cast<B*>( a )` or `static_cast< B*>( a )` may not yield the same address when they succeed.

That is because when multiply inherited, the secondary inheritance creates multiple classes and vtables in the object.  When this happens, the static_cast, dynamic_cast adjust the base address of the object to find the correct embedded class base address.

The fact that dynamic_cast and static_cast may change the address, is why reinterpret_cast is discouraged.  It can result in a value which doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Reinterpret cast will always return a pointer. It may just not be a valid pointer in the sense that it actually points to an object of type B.

If B has more than one base class, and A is not the first base class, reinterpret cast will do the wrong thing and fail to perform necessary adjustment to the pointer.

For your usecase you should use a static cast which has the advantage that the compiler will check whether B is actually derived from A and perform any needed adjustment. No runtime overhead is incurred by additional checks, however there will be no warning if the object is not actually of type B and the program will fail arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, `reinterpret_cast` is the wrong solution, use `dynamic_cast` instead:

```
void abc(A * a) {
    B *b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    if (b) {
        def(b);
    }
}
```